# How to Add php spesific array element integer value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like follows:

```
$table_arr[] = {
               [0][['arg1'] => data1, ['arg2'] => data2, ['arg3'] => data, ['line_count'] => 2],
               [1][['arg1'] => data1_1, ['arg2'] => data2_1, ['arg3'] => data3_, ['line_count'] => 4]
               };
```

I want to add a line_count value in the array(in above array 2 + 4 = 6)

so i can do this using php foreach. Is there any function for below logic (without using a loop)?

```
$val = 0;               
foreach($table_arr as key => value){
   if(key == 'line_count'){
      $val = $val + value;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a native function in PHP, it's really specific functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your php version >=5.5, then try using `array_columns` with `array_sum`, but still there will be internal looping

```
echo array_sum(array_column($table_arr,'line_count'));
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/103737)

Answer (score 1):

Can do better like

```
foreach($table_arr as $arr){       
      $val += $arr['line_count'];       
}  
echo $val;
```

Comment: Thats same as my solution. Is there any solution with out using `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

You schould look in to phps array_sum https://www.php.net/array_sum

this functions sums all values in an array returning the total value.